# Perl script won't run subscripts in relative path

Tags: linux, perl, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I've got a perl script: run.pl that's been called by cron every minute.

The only thing run.pl does is call two other scripts: download.pl and parse.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

do 'download.pl';
do 'parse.pl';
print "done!\n";
```

In download.pl and parse.pl are two prints to with "done downloading" and "done parsing"
Now I output the script to /var/log/script.log and check for the script to run.

The run.pl script is doing fine, it outputs "done!" to the logfile. But the other two scripts aren't called. I think it is a relative path problem, it works when I use the absolute path.

But that's the problem, the script is in teststage and changes paths every time, it would be a mess to always change te absolute path.

Is there a way to let the scripts run from the relative path?

Edit:
When I run it myself from the commandline with "perl run.pl" it runs the scripts without a problem.

Comment: are the other scripts always in the same directory so that './download.pl' would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron jobs don't run with the same environment that a shell login would see. A cron job will usually have the cron's user's home directory as it's default working directory.
One option to get around this is to use [`FindBin`](http://p3rl.org/FindBin) to locate the directory the script is in and base your paths off of that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

do $Bin.'download.pl';
do $Bin.'parse.pl';
print "done!\n";
```

You might be better off turning `download.pl` and `parse.pl` into real modules, it might save you some effort in the long run.

Comment: @tchrist, I agree, see the last sentence of my answer, but if the OP has found a rare cases where `do` is the right choice, then I'd argue `FindBin` is a good answer.

Comment: I’m something of a fan of `FindBin` myself, although this does get me in hot water with people whose opinions I generally respect.

Answer (score 5):

Um, why are you using `do`?  That doesn’t “call” a program, you know!

Are these library modules or programs?

Also, programs are expected to be found in `$ENV{PATH}`, whereas libraries are expected to be found in `@INC`.  Those are almost certainly different things.

My advice is:

1. To call another program in `$ENV{PATH}`, use `system()` or backticks.
2. To load a library in `@INC`, use `require` or `use`.
3. Reserve `do FILE` to exotic wizardly purposes that almost surely do not apply here.

Comment: @Hasturkun: You hardly need quote my own writings back to me. ☹

Comment: Sorry, I must have glossed over the third paragraph

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootdir=&#x60;dirname "$0"&#x60;;

### call your scripts here relative to $rootdir
```

doesn't help?

Comment: Don't use a shell command when Perl provides a module that will to the same thing without the cost/security issues of using the shell. `use File::Basename qw(dirname);`